# Из-за клавиатуры Activity поднимается наверх

Tags: xml, android, java

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулась с такой проблемой.
Когда открываю Активити, окно выглядит так:

[image: Imgur]

А когда верхняя EditView получает фокус и появляется клавиатура, то окно выглядит вот так:

[image: Imgur]

Как можно избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/315219/android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-layout-%D1%81-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиграйте с атрибутом [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!!!